# C program does not run in PopOS terminal

Tags: c, linux, gcc, terminal

I have the following file `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
printf("Hi\n");
fprintf(stderr, "Hello World\n");
return 2;
}
```

And then in the Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS terminal, I execute:

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

and then

```
test
```

and it just immediately returns without showing anything. When I execute

```
echo $?
```

it writes `1`.
How can I run C programs in my Linux terminal?

Comment: `test` runs the shell builtin function with this name. Try `./test`

Comment: @teapot418 I don't think it's a builtin, at least in most shells.  Normally they just run `/usr/bin/test`.  But yeah, I suspect that's what OP is running, rather than `./test`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, test does exist on my system, however now I learned that if it would have not, the command would result in an error, must do ./test anyway... Thanks.